# on the need, at the need, in the need

Tags: grammar

on the need, at the need, in the need, for the need

What is the difference?

> There is no daylight between the United States, the Republic of Korea and Japan on the need to continue to isolate North Korea economically and diplomatically until they abandon their nuclear and ballistic missile programme

Comment: The proper preposition depends on the rest of the sentence. Good examples for each can easily be made with the right sentence.

Comment: Client differences in the need for autonomy are an important determinant of their response to directive and less directive interventions

Comment: The coefficient alpha for the need for learning was .70. All alphas for the 3M elemental traits were above .80. Correlations were calculated among the need for learning, the original NCOG scale, the reduced NCOG scale, and the openness to experience scale.

Comment: Among those at the need-for-esteem level, there are equal proportions of "less" and "more tolerant," while for the self- actualizers there is a larger proportion of "more" than "less tolerant" respondents. Among the sociological background variables, only in the case of religion was ...

Comment: fdf l324 - What are those comments supposed to mean? Shouldn't they be part of your question?

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are the bits that translate least well between languages. Many English prepositions have twenty or more different, specific meanings. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on), **on** has 26 meanings. The prepositions that are valid in a particular context are generally determined by the preceding verb, rather than the following object: in this case, **the need** has little effect on the meaning of the preposition.

The particular meaning in this case is RELATING TO. Another example of the same meaning would be:

> The minister has refused to comment on the allegations.

[at](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/at), [in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in) and [for](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for) don't really have suitable meanings for this context, though **in** as a CHARACTERISTIC is close.